# subset sum - lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a subset sum problem in lisp.
Example: `(subsetsum '(1 2 3) 5)` = `(2 3)`, `(subsetsum '(1 5 3) 2)` = `nil`.

I can only use functions

```
(atom x) 
(null x)
(eq x y)
(equal x y)
(numberp x)
(append x y)
(car x)
(cdr x)
(cons x y) 
(if x y z)
(cond ... ) 
(let ((x y) (u v)) z)
(let* ((x y) (u v)) z)
(defun ...)
(quote x) and its short form 'x
(list x1 x2 ...)
(print ...)
(sort L fun)
```

Can I get any hint?

Answer (score 1):

A simplified reasoning for this problem is the following:

1. you have a list `L` and a number `S`
2. either the first element of the list is part of a solution or it's not
3. if the first is part of the solution then you need to use it and a solution of the simpler problem `(rest L) (- S (first L))`
4. if it's not part of the solution then you need to solve instead the simpler problem `(rest L) S`
5. there are a few cases in which you can avoid doing the search... for example if the list is empty and `S` is not zero, or if all elements are greater than zero and even summing all of them you cannot reach `S`...